# Accessing Multidimensional Arrays Returned by Php With Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to access individual data created in a multidimensional php array with jquery. I can see the data is there in the console but when I'm trying to post the data, Php `$_POST` returns undefined.

register.php

```
  //put customer information in array so that it can be reused in js
  $customerArray = array(
      array(
          'customerid' => $customerId, 
          'countrycode' => $countryCode,
          'mobilephone' => $mobilePhoneCode
      )
  );

  //encode in json
  echo json_encode($customerArray);
```

jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'queries/register.php',
  data: formvalues, // serializes the form's elements.
  success: function(customerarr) {

    console.log(customerarr);
    //get customer array information
    var customerID = customerarr['customerid'];
    var countrycode = customerarr['countrycode'];
    var mobilephone = customerarr['mobilephone'];

  }
  //function to send a new verification number 
  $('#sendnewverificationNumber').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //capture the customerid who previously signed up
    var newnumberform = 'customerID=' + encodeURIComponent(customerID) +
      '&countrycode=' + encodeURIComponent(countrycode) +
      '&mobilephone=' + encodeURIComponent(mobilephone);
    //ajax POST
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'queries/validation.php',
      data: newnumberform, // serializes the form's elements.
      success: function(newdata) {

        console.log(newdata);
        //write message
        var newmsg = 'We went a new verification number to your mobile.'
        //append class to make it show
        $("#validationpmessage").addClass("text-success");
        //display message in the modal                                                                        
        $("#validationpmessage").html(newmsg);
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Why are you returning a multidimensional array to begin with? It doesn't seem necessary. Just return a simple array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Why not?

Comment: Why not? Because you don't need the outer array and that is why you can't access the properties you are looking for. The javascript object you want is needlessly nested in a javascript array

Comment: Because you're returning a more complicated structure than you need? To fetch a value, you will now need to do: `newdata[0].customerid` instead of just `newdata.customerid`. Just seems unnecessary.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Yeah but I want to use constants instead of the numeric thingy. It's just prettier in case I want to add more data.

Comment: _"Php $_POST returns undefined"_ - Where? I don't see you trying to access any `$_POST`-data anywhere?

Comment: _"I want to use constants instead of the numeric thingy"_ - ??? I have no idea what that means. If you return the data from PHP as you do now, you need to access it with: `newdata[0].customerid` (if that is what you mean by "numeric thingy"). I don't see what that has to do with constants?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Alright. My mistake. I get it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I have followed your advice. Changed the old array now to this   `$customerArray = array('customerid' => $customerId, 
                      'countrycode' => $countryCode,
                      'mobilephone' => $mobilePhoneCode
                    );`

Comment: Then you will get an object back and you can access the parameters as I showed you before: `customerarr.customerid`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: When I try to access each single key like this `var customerID = customerarr['customerid'];` or `var customerID = customerarr.customerid;` when I print the value in the console like this `console.log(customerID);` it returns 'undefined'.

Comment: In your question, it says that the `$customerArray`-code is in `array.php`, but you're calling `queries/register.php`? Your question and your code is all over the place. Please rewrite your question and be explicit about what code is where. Also, show us where you're using `$_POST`, which you claim doesn't work. Until then, I'm out...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I have edited that. I got carried away.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: If I do `console.log(customerarr)` I see the full array `{"customerid":56572018,"countrycode":"+1","mobilephone":"9075558882"}`

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json',` to your ajax call to make sure that jQuery parse the response as json and not as a string. You can also add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before you echo the response in your PHP code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I should have thought about that. There problem solved. Thanks.